# How can I use the Add brush in Particle Edit mode?

Tags: particles, edit-mode

How can I exclusivity use the *Add brush* in *Particle Edit* mode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default the particle system has hair growing form each face, to *exclusively* use the *Add brush* to place the hairs you must first set the *Number* to `0`.
[image: particle settings]

Then you can go into Particle Edit mode and use the add brush to place the hairs.

[image: animated gif]

Comment: You must also have "Faces" selected in Particle system > Emission > Emit From.